# Android Alpha APK published, but still shows up as missing

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-install-apk

I have published my application as an alpha release, initially English(US) only, but eventually added "Rest of World".  The application says published (No more pending updates) and provides a link "https://play.google.com/apps/testing/{app name}".  Navigating there, even if I log in with the user logged in that has been invited, it still stays item not found.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Try using incognito mode

Comment: Please wait 2-3 hour after publish app. it will take some time to be live.

Comment: @CapDroid Published last night.

Comment: Did you accept as tester ???

Comment: @mach Not sure how incognito mode will work, since you need to be actually logged in.

Comment: @CapDroid I did accept as a tester.  Gives me a link, which I an open with either IE, Chrome or play - same result "Item Not Found"

Comment: I had to surf up to the ../apps/testing and then log in using a incognito-tab due to Chrome keeping some cookie about my other account.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne must have login with tester account in playstore...

Comment: @mach I have factory reset the phone.   Only account is the tester.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne are you trying to open in mobile or PC?

Comment: @CapDroid I have created a brand new user, given access to testing, but not publish, etc.  Received initial and subsequent tester invites - all accepted.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thought you were surfing in to the test-page through your computer.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne so you didn't publish app in alpha mode ?

Comment: @mach No problem.  Open to all suggestions.

Comment: @CapDroid It is currently published in alpha mode ONLY.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne [check this link](https://help.gamesalad.com/hc/en-us/articles/203536123-7-6-In-App-Purchases-IAP-for-Google-Play) may be helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony Home.

You have to set up [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview) or [Google+ Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities) for testing Application.
And add your tester into that `Google Group` or `G+ Community`

Here is full description and step by step instruction about how to test Alpha or Beta APK from Google Play Store.

[Click Here](https://help.gamesalad.com/hc/en-us/articles/203536123-7-6-In-App-Purchases-IAP-for-Google-Play)